# Error when compiling for x86 but not for x64

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, operator-precedence

I have written the following code:

```
struct Element
{
    int value;
};

struct Array
{
    operator Element*();
    operator const Element*() const;
    Element& operator[](const size_t nIndex);
    const Element& operator[](const size_t nIndex) const;
};

int main()
{
    Array values;
    if (values[0].value == 10)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine in x64. But in x86 I get a compiler error:

```
error C2666: 'Array::operator []': 4 overloads have similar conversions
note: could be 'const Element &Array::operator [](const std::size_t) const'
note: or       'Element &Array::operator [](const std::size_t)'
note: while trying to match the argument list '(Array, int)'
error C2228: left of '.value' must have class/struct/union
```

If I comment out the implicit conversions func, or add the `explicit` prefix, the code is compilable in x86.

But I can't understand why this code makes trouble.

Why can't the compiler decide to use an implicit conversion first, or array accessor first? I thought `operator[]` is [higher in precedence](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: We won't be able to help you unless you make a [mcve] that reproduces the issue. Go to http://gcc.godbolt.org and figure out a short snippet that demonstrates the problem (that is, compiles in x64 mode and doesn't compile in x86 mode).

Comment: Implicit conversions are convenient, but they're also a huge source of problems. It's best to avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: I've added a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `0` which is an `int` needs doesn't directly match the type of the arguments to your `[]` operator and therefore a conversion is needed.

However it does match the built in `[]` operator for the `Element` pointer type. Clang gives a more descriptive error message in this case: https://godbolt.org/z/FB3DzG (note I've changed the parameter to `int64_t` to make this fail on x64).

The compiler has to do one conversion to use your class operator (the index from `int` to `size_t`) and one conversion to use the built in operator (from `Array` to `Element*`) it is ambiguous which one it should use.

It works on x64 as your class operator still only requires a single conversion for the index but the built in operator needs 2, 1 from `Array` to `Element*` and one for the index from `int` to `int64_t`, this makes your class operator a better match and is therefore not ambiguous.

The solution is to either make the conversion operator explicit (which is a good idea anyway) or to ensure that the type you are passing as your  index matches the type your operator is expecting. In your example case you can simply pass `0U` instead of `0`.

Comment: Great explaination!
Thank you very much!